# Identifying anonymous users

Tags: authentication, identity, anonymous

If I had a poll on my site, and I didn't want to require a registration to vote, but I only wanted each visit one, how might I do this?

Let's say a visitor from IP 123.34.243.57 visits the site and votes. Would it then be safe to disallow anyone from 123.34.243.* from voting? Is this a good strategy?

What's another one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a fundamental challenge with all voting sites on the Internet, and you're just breaking the surface of the problem.

The way you've phrased it, you "only want to allow each visit one [vote]" indicates that you want to allow them to vote once each time they open their browser and go to the site.  I don't think this is really what you seek.

I suspect what you want is that a given individual *Person* can vote only once ever (per survey, maybe).

The problem is, once you've framed the question properly, the problem becomes much more clear. You're not trying to identify an Internet node (IP address), visit (session cookie), browser instance (persistent cookie), or computer (difficult also to identify).

You can use techniques with Cookies, and they were suitably for a typical user.  Subverting this technique is as easy as
- Clearing your cookies in the browser,
- Disallowing cookies in the browser,
- Opening another browser,
- Walking to another computer,
- Using an anonimizer,
- ... endless other ways.

You can do validation by e-mail address, but you indicated you don't want to do registration, so I don't believe that solves you problem either.

If you really need to identify a unique user for a voting system, you'll need to have some authority who's willing to vouch for the identity of any given user, or only allow the software to be accessed from a trusted platform.

The first technique requires registration (and often a costly and time-consuming registration at that), that verifies the actual legal name and location of the individual. Then, using Public Key Infrastructure (aka Digital Certificates), you can identify an individual person based on the credentials he supplies.

The second technique, requiring a trusted platform, relies on the hardware following certain pre-determined behavior.  You could, for example, create a voting site that works through the XBox 360 or iPhone.  You would create an app that is installed to one of those devices.  Based on the way the platform is protected, you could use uniqueness characteristics, such as the hardware address or Live ID on the XBox 360 or the hardware address or telephone number on the iPhone, to get general assurance that the user is the same one who has visited before.  Because you have control over the application and the user specifically does not, due to the nature of the trusted platform, you have reasonable assurance that most users will not be able to subvert the intent of the application.

I suspect this is a long-winded way of saying you can do it, but it's a far from easy problem to solve.

Consider political elections and how much resources and energy goes into making those fair and anonymous, and still it's a very challenging problem.

Answer (score 2):

Using the public IP for this would probably be a bad idea. Unique visitors from the same corporate LAN would all look like one user if you use this approach.

Perhaps cookies? I believe that is what most sites use.

Combine with some sort of monitoring, automatic or manually (for instance log file analysis). Be suspicious of traffic patterns that indicate a script.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use IP address or IP spans to identify unique users. For several reasons:

1. Stopping a whole span will stop users who haven't voted.
2. People who get an IP adress dynamically will get a different IP address later.
3. People in a local network (like a big company) share the same public IP address.

You could use a cookie to flag who has voted. That will be a lot better as it doesn't hit as blindly, but it's of course not completely accurate as people can clear the cookies and browse with more than one browser.

To make a completely accurate identification of the users so that you are really sure that noone votes more than once, you need a login for the users. Well, with the exception for the fact that people could create more than one account of course...

Comment: I think the blocking a particular IP (not the whole IP range) is better. because users can cheat in other solutions, but you cannot change your IP! in worst case they can use some proxy websites to vote more than once.

Comment: @Isaac: Actually, when you have a dynamic IP you only have it for a certain time, for example an hour. After that you get a new IP, and although most of the time you get the same as before, it can very well change. Also, everyone behind a firewall share the same IP, so there can be hundreds of users on a single IP.

Answer (score 0):

block a ip range is not a good strategy, you can have 2 option to indentify the already voted user, their IP and cookie. after they voted, set a cookie and don't allow them to vote again.

they can clear cookie and change the IP, but it's acceptable for anonymous voting, if you want a better strategy, let's them register for voting

Answer (score 0):

You should block just that particular IP, not the whole IP range!

If you don't have a registration, this is the best solution, but not for users!

You can prevent someone from voting multiple times. but you also may block some other users from voting and that's because of NAT.

[Network Address Translation](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FNetwork_address_translation&ei=4omZSvKmJ5jcmgOC2Z2nDQ&usg=AFQjCNE3M-Gg7yuoxBh5CKp2LjD13qOywA&sig2=eK3GklJDREX0houLKwEVBA) (or NAT) allows multiple users use a single IP to access internet.

But this is OK because NAT is not used heavily and few users will be disallowed from voting.

However, cookies is not the good solution. because the user can easily erase the browser cookies and vote again. Even worse, he/she can write a script to vote automatically many times!

Comment: I belive NAT *is* quite heavily used. At least in my experience. Every workplace network that I have encountered use private IP ranges and NAT/IP masquerading.

Comment: NAT often used in places like Universities that identifying a particular user is not the case. Because the NAT ruin the TCP/IP approach (that any IP should identify a single station) using it could have side-effects like this and any administrator want to use NAT should accept the limitations that will be forced to his/her users.

Comment: Re: _NAT is not used heavily_

_"We ﬁnd that more than 90 % of DSL lines use NAT gateways to connect to the Internet and that 10 % of DSL lines have multiple hosts that are active at the same time. Overall, up to 52 % of lines have multiple hosts. Our ﬁndings point out that using IPs as host identiﬁers may introduce substantial errors and therefore should be used with caution."_

 -- http://www.icir.org/gregor/papers/pam11-nat.pdf